# Letting the ruby environment know the file location

Tags: ruby, debugging

While creating a [gem](https://github.com/runefs/Moby) for DCI I've found the need to be able to tell the environment the location in source of specific expressions.

The reason being that in my particular cse most of the code is handed to `instance_eval` giving the location of the instance_eval as the error location. However for debugging purposes I'd like to be able to flag where the actual error location is.

```
context :MyContext do
  role :foo do
    def bar
      player.baz
    end
  end
end
```

Say that the above code is incorrect, that the object identified by `player` doesn't have a method called baz. I'd like the runtime to fail and indicate the 4th line above as the error location and not an arbitrary line in the source of the gem

I'll be able to instrument the code to update values as expressions are evaluated, my problem is I don't know what to update

Comment: The `caller` method gives you a stack trace (array?). You may also want to look at `respond_to?` and the Method class: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html

Comment: @s, can you explain?atya not sure how I would use that information to set the location used by the environment. I know the location up front and the stack trace is "inaccurate" and that's what I'm trying to "fix" so I don't think I understand what you are suggesting that I do